# regex - length 9, first character 9

Tags: regex

I am trying to create a regex to match a telephone number with the following criteria:

- Length 9
- First character must be a 9
- The remaining 8 must be numeric 0-9

This is what I'm trying, but it does not work:

```
$(".ValidarTelefono").keypress(function (e) {        
    tecla = (document.all) ? e.keyCode : e.which;
    if (tecla == 8) return true;
    patron = /^9\d{8}$/;
    te = String.fromCharCode(tecla);
    return patron.test(te);
});
```

Could someone tell me where I went wrong?

Comment: An easy enough task. Where are you having trouble?

Answer (score 1):

This regex will do your job in every regex engine I know:

```
9[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]
```

Many (but not all) regex engines offer various ways to simplify that:

- You may be able to substitute `\d` for `[0-9]`
- You may be able to use an enumerated quantifier instead of eight literal repeats of the digit sub-pattern (i.e. `[0-9]{8}` or `\d{8}`)

Additionally, depending on your purpose for this regex, you may or may not also want also to anchor it to the beginning and/or end of the input (by inserting a `^` at the beginning and/or a `$` at the end).

Answer (score 0):

### [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/vY9uN2/1)

```
^9\d{8}$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/_5QUrhAYLF2AgRsg)

is the pure most pure version because this doesn't allow for any separators.

Comment: Nice flow chart, but what is "most pure" supposed to mean?

Comment: @JohnBollinger it doesn't allow for separators, it is just 9 numbers starting with the number 9.  No `.`, `-`, `(`, or `)` is what I meant.  Edited answer to attempt to add this context.

Comment: @abc123 i'm using this, but it does not work. $(".ValidarTelefono").keypress(function (e) {        
    tecla = (document.all) ? e.keyCode : e.which;
    if (tecla == 8) return true;
    patron = /^9\d{8}$/;
    te = String.fromCharCode(tecla);
    return patron.test(te);
}); Could someone tell me where I went wrong?

Comment: sure, can you tell me what is in `te`?